# copy the content of the file to other location

Tags: linux, bash, awk, copy

i have a text file that contain output results of a function(path line and just below the results) and i want to copy only the results, mentioned below of each path line to the file that is mentioned in name=.... and want to paste at the last column of the file

my data is here saved in list.txt

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/liu/datalist/20180603_190202_5.0_38_CD.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
0.9821305886510053
0.9822639336394542
0.9820650754926169
0.9826369946635649
0.983048680372995
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/liu/datalist/20150603_190202_12.0_36_CD.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
0.984263067046808
0.9821305886510053
0.9822639336394542
0.9820650754926169
0.9826369946635649
0.983048680372995
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/liu/datalist/20120603_190202_9.0_35_CD.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
0.984263067046808
0.982871209110385
0.9830143471771022
0.9860952410409616
0.9897257569597108
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/liu/datalist/20100603_190202_125.0_36_CD.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
0.9860794488788789
0.9838808626335948
0.9829656043793615
0.9868238026934462
0.9972756725839034
0.9882482212913676
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/liu/datalist/20240603_190202_265.0_36_CD.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
0.9856758910581078
0.9849158515561436
0.9838016078370099
0.9854127382758501
0.9880763165814402
```

i tried the code below: not getting proper idea to do this.Hope some expert would help me.Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in `list.txt`
cp cat|list.txt > name
```

Details explanation:
suppose we take 20180603_190202_5.0_38_CD.txt file to the consideration.This named file is already present inside /home/liu/datalist directory and it contains file like

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9
3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7 
4 5 6 7 8
```

and i want the file to be as below

```
1 2 3 4 5 0.9821305886510053
5 6 7 8 9 0.9822639336394542
3 4 5 6 7 0.9820650754926169
3 4 5 6 7 0.9826369946635649
4 5 6 7 8 0.983048680372995
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using associative arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A filetemp

while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ "name='"(.*?.txt) ]]
    then
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        filetemp[$name]=$(mktemp)
    else
        [ -n "$name" ] && echo "$line" >> "${filetemp[$name]}"
    fi
done < list.txt

for name in "${!filetemp[@]}"
do
    paste -d ' ' "$name" "${filetemp[$name]}" > "${name}.tmp"
    mv -f "${name}.tmp" "$name"
done
```

EDIT: Forgot about this but, just in case, it would be a good idea to clean up the temporary files created by `mktemp` after they are no longer required:

```
for name in "${!filetemp[@]}"
do
    tempfile="${filetemp[$name]}"
    paste -d ' ' "$name" "$tempfile" > "${name}.tmp"
    mv -f "${name}.tmp" "$name"
    rm -f "$tempfile"
done
```

EDIT 2: As pointed by @lucasgvarela, the `trap` command could be a more elegant way of removing the temporary files when the `EXIT` signal is triggered:

```
trap 'rm -f "${filetemp[@]}"' EXIT

for name in "${!filetemp[@]}"
do
    paste -d ' ' "$name" "${filetemp[$name]}" > "${name}.tmp"
    mv -f "${name}.tmp" "$name"
done
```

Comment: where to include my input file name inorder to test the code

Comment: It must be in your current working directory (`cwd`), that is in the same directory that you're currently executing the script from, if manually. For good measure, the best practice would be using the absolute instead of the relative path, but I don't know where the file is located here (e.g. if the file is inside `/root`, rewrite `done < list.txt` to `done < /root/list.txt`).

Comment: k...let me check....my originalfiles contain little bit longer path...thus does it require to change something in code

Comment: @Rfroes87 about your edit, what do you think about the TRAP command, isn't that a good way to improve the removal of this mktemp files?

Comment: @lucasgvarela Thank you very much for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of this command. Just tested it and it works! Will edit the question with this information.

Comment: @Rfroes87 I'm glad to help, that's the beauty of being human, we learn new things every day, by the way, you did a pretty code :D, I fixed/edited mine right now, the old version was ugly

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: New code, fixing the old ugly code :D

Result

```
$ cat 20150603_190202_12.0_36_CD.txt 
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9
3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8

$ cat 20180603_190202_5.0_38_CD.txt 
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9
3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8

$ ./test.sh 

$ cat 20150603_190202_12.0_36_CD.txt 
1 2 3 4 5 0.984263067046808
5 6 7 8 9 0.9821305886510053
3 4 5 6 7 0.9822639336394542
3 4 5 6 7 0.9820650754926169
4 5 6 7 8 0.9826369946635649

$ cat 20180603_190202_5.0_38_CD.txt 
1 2 3 4 5 0.9821305886510053
5 6 7 8 9 0.9822639336394542
3 4 5 6 7 0.9820650754926169
3 4 5 6 7 0.9826369946635649
4 5 6 7 8 0.983048680372995
```

Code

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

cat list.txt | cut -d '/' -f5- | sed "s/' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>//" > new_list.txt

while read -r line
do
  if [[ "$line" =~ ".txt" ]]; then
    count=0
    filename="$line"
    touch "$filename"
  else
    count=$(($count+1))
    originalline=$(sed -n ${count}p "$filename")
    sed -i "0,/^$originalline\$/s//$originalline $line/" "$filename"
  fi
done < "new_list.txt"

rm new_list.txt
```

Comment: what actually 5 in     if [[ $count -eq 5 ]]; then...can u please tell me

Comment: @anonymossi this was a counter, but I'm still trying to fix that code to a better version that doesn't depends on counters..

Comment: @anonymossi heyy, now please read again the code, it's much better, the counter is just one way to know in which line the replace should happen. the old counter was doing something very different and erroneous ....

Comment: This is an interesting alternative; it avoids needing to create an associative array - which as far as I know is bash-specific with the `declare` command - and doing 2 loops, which could make it better optimized than my approach.